# SendGrid mail not sending (web and smtp)

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I've been trying for a while to get my emails to send using SendGrid. I've set up a test PHP script:

```
<?php

require_once('../resources/functions/sendgrid/lib/SendGrid.php');
SendGrid::register_autoloader();
require_once('../resources/functions/unirest/lib/Unirest.php');

$sendgrid = new SendGrid('my_username', 'my_password');

$sendgrid_email = new SendGrid\Email();
$sendgrid_email->addTo('my_email@gmail.com')->
                setFrom('Name <noreply@my_domain.co.uk>')->
                setSubject('Name | Test Mail')->
                setText("TEST MESSAGE");
$sendgrid->smtp->send($sendgrid_email);

echo 'mail sent';

?>
```

I've tried this using both the web and smtp methods, both methods get to the "mail sent" echo, yet neither actually appear in my inbox, and when I check my SendGrid account I still have 0 sent emails.

EDIT:

Ok, so I got it working. Removed the "name ", changed it to just "noreply@my_domain.co.uk". However, I want to define the name using the first method - any way of doing this?

ANOTHER EDIT:

Alright, Nick Q's answer fixed the rest of the issues I was having. And for anyone who is wondering, the way you set a from name (i.e Example ) is by having setFrom as just the email [setFrom("noreply@example.com")] and then using setFromName [setFromName("Example")].

Comment: did you bother trying to capture the return value of the `->send()` call? It's pretty bad to say 'sent' when you don't confirm that it actually WAS sent.

Comment: check the mail server log

Comment: Marc B, this was just a test script so I didn't have to register a new user every time I wanted to test. Just wanted to ensure it was actually GETTING to that stage in the script, so I didn't care what it echoed. Dagon, what do you mean? I have no way of checking the logs on the mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `SendGrid::register_autoloader();` after also requiring Unirest.

Otherwise your script looks good.